# .xlsx file getting created outside the folder, but not inside it

Tags: java, android, excel, file-io

I am trying to create a **.xlsx** file inside a folder ( *programmatically* created by me) using the **jspreadsheet-1.0.jar**. The file gets created with around **3 KB** size and I can open it and view it, if I create it outside the folder in the path **/storage/sdcard0**, but if I create **within** the folder, it just shows a **0 KB** file which cannot be opened. My code is as follows:

**Folder creation:**

```
    String FOLDERNAME="/foldername";
                File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FOLDERNAME);
                if(!dir.exists())
                {
                    dir.mkdir();
                }
```

**File generation (within a folder)**:

```
public void generate(Context mainContext)
{
     Worksheet sheet1 = new Worksheet();
           sheet1.set("A1",new Cell(100));

          context = mainContext;

        Workbook book1 = new Workbook();
        book1.getSheets().add(sheet1);

        try {
                     book1.save(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/foldername/file.xlsx");
              } catch (IOException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
              }

        new SingleMediaScanner(context,Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/foldername/file.xlsx");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
 book1.save(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foldername/file.xlsx");
```

instead of

```
  book1.save(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/foldername/file.xlsx");
```

Comment: Never mind.. there seems to be a conflict with some other file generation functions i am using.. thanks anyways for the response :)